# Bottom Overflowed by Infinite Pixels by using Stack inside Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a stack widget to display animations inside a screen. I am using only 70% of the screen and the rest I have kept it unused. I want to display something else there. When I am wrapping my stack widget inside a column it is giving the error: **Bottom Overflowed by Infinite Pixels**.

I tried adding a custom height using Container and SizedBox. Also tried using `SingleChildScrollView`. Still the same error.

Code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: whiteColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.72,
                child: FlareActor(
                  'assets/videos/stars.flr',
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  animation: 'Blink',
                  controller: _controller,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: 0.6,
                  child: FlareActor(
                    'assets/videos/talking-earth.flr',
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    animation: 'activated',
                    controller: _controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Positioned(
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.8,
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                child: Text(
                  "Published",
                  style: GoogleFonts.ptSansNarrow(
                      color: whiteColor,
                      fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text("Test"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No matter if you use `Stack` inside a `Column` or standalone, it will always overflow if things are going out of the boundary. You need to decide, if `Stack` is the correct widget for your use case? As a workaround, you can use `overflow: Overflow.visible`.

Comment: Try to wrap your Stack with a Container first, setting a predefined height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your stack with a Container first, setting a predefined height. This is because the Stack size relies on its parent.

Here's the official documentation on Stack: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html